# How to get the metrics from an ICompilationUnit with checkstyle

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I've implemented a method that gets all the ICompilationUnit from a selected eclipse project. but I need to get the metrics of these files, such as how many lines a method has.

I was given the checkstyle to get the metrics, but I do not know how to get those metrics.

I'm using checkstyle to get the metrics, but I'm not sure how to get these metrics.

```
public  List<ICompilationUnit> getCompilationUnits(IJavaProject javaProject) throws NullPointerException {
    List<ICompilationUnit> units = new LinkedList<ICompilationUnit>();
        try {
                IPackageFragmentRoot[] packageFragmentRoots = javaProject.getAllPackageFragmentRoots();
                for(int i = 0; i < packageFragmentRoots.length; i++) {
                IPackageFragmentRoot packageFragmentRoot = packageFragmentRoots[i];
                IJavaElement[] fragments = packageFragmentRoot.getChildren();
                for(int j = 0; j < fragments.length; j++) {
                   IPackageFragment fragment = (IPackageFragment)fragments[j];
                   IJavaElement[] javaElements = fragment.getChildren();
                   for(int k = 0; k < javaElements.length; k++) {
                      IJavaElement javaElement = javaElements[k];
                      if(javaElement.getElementType() == IJavaElement.COMPILATION_UNIT) {
                         units.add( (ICompilationUnit)javaElement);
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
          catch(Exception e) {

          }
          return units;
       }
}
```

This is the code I use to get a list with all the ICompilationUnit of a project.

What would be the best way to get metrics from one of these ICompilationUnit using checkstyle?.

Edit: How I can generate an AST using the existing checkstyle methods to parse the IJavaProject obtained ?

Comment: Checkstyle is a static analyzer on the source code. It doesn't work with other trees like eclipse besides it's own.

Comment: Some way to pass the code I want to parse and get the metrics using your tree?

Comment: Have you checked their developer documentation? http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writinglisteners.html

Comment: Have you tried using a parser like [JavaParser](http://javaparser.org/) instead?

Comment: I just tried using AST from eclipse and using PMD, in case PMD can not find anything in the documentation for this.

Comment: @artur-s-farias can you give us some more information on what you are trying to achieve? Does this have to be using the eclipse's tree? Is this for an eclipse project or a normal Java project?

Comment: I'm developing a plugin for eclipse to analyze the code written in it, but with eclipse I'm just having difficulty getting metrics to parse the code.

Comment: Getting ICompilationUnit was a way to find the java project files being written to be able to do an analysis. The idea is a kind of linter for detecting bad smells.

Comment: I tried using PMD but I can not understand how to use it as a plugin

Comment: @artur-s-farias Why don't you use eclipse-cs and just make a custom check in Checkstyle that processes the AST using Checkstyle's tree. You can copy code from checkstyle's other checks if you need pieces of it. http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html

Comment: I am trying to follow the documentation but I do not know how to get the DetailAST object of ICompilationUnit obtained by eclipse. I tried to use AST from eclipse but it does not work.

Comment: @artur-s-farias DetailAST is used inside Checkstyle's world. ICompilationUnit is used inside Eclipse's world. You can't intermingle the 2 unless you build code to bridge the gap. With eclipse-cs, I am saying you shouldn't write any eclipse plugin code and just write a check to be used inside Checkstyle, but it depends on what you will do with the metrics you are looking for.